# What is the issue with this C++ code?

Tags: c++

I want to use algorithm for finding a student score. I want to enter a number and if this number is among scores, then find the name and student number and if not, I receive it is not available.But, there is a problem that I cannot find that. Do you have any solution?
Thanks,

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#define n 3

using namespace std;
class student{
public:
    int stno,score,i;
    string name;
};


int main(){
    int l;
   vector<student> my_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        student new_student;

        cout << "Student Number: ";
        cin >> new_student.stno;
        cout << "Score: ";
        cin >> new_student.score;
       cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> new_student.name;

        my_vector.push_back(new_student);
    }

cout<<"which score are you thinking about?=";
cin>>l;

(find(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),[] (student const& scores){
    if (scores.score ==l)
        cout<<"it is available"<<scores.name<<scores.stno;
    else
      cout<<"nit available;}));

cin.get();
cin.get();
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: pushing same instance of new_student every time through loop

Comment: @CarlH -- It is perfectly fine to do this.  The vector makes a copy of the `student` instance.

Comment: anyhow it is not the same instance, but each iteration a new one is created. Maybe it would be better to create the instance outside of the loop and actually do push the same instance on each iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `std::find_if`, not `std::find`.

You're supposed to return `true` or `false` depending on whether the data has been found or not.  Then the returned iterator from `std::find_if` can be checked:

```
auto iter = std::find_if(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(),
                      [] (student const& scores){ return scores.score ==l; });

if ( iter != my_vector.end())
      cout<<"it is available"<<(*iter).name<<(*iter).stno;
else
      cout<<"not available;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. When is the time that find should be used?

Comment: The `find` should be used when you have a single value that needs to be found without usage of a predicate.  

For example, if you had an array of integers, and you want to find the number `10` in the array, then you use `std::fnd`.  However, if you wanted to find the first number that when you add 5 to it, you get a multiple of 2, then `std::find_if` would be used to describe what you're searching for.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable helps.I have two more questions.1)What is the function of return? where does 'l' return? 2) why do you use iter when you define if ( iter != my_vector.end()) and you use pointer + iter when you use cout<<"it is available"<<(*iter).name<<(*iter).stno; I appreciate you for your help.

Comment: The `std::find_if` returns an iterator to the found item.  If it equals to the container's `end()` iterator, then the item wasn't found.  If the item was found, then dereferencing the iterator gives you the found item.

Comment: Thanks, Please explain a bit about my second question.

Comment: I think my explanation explains both.  You don't see that the iterator is being dereferenced?